# Pandas groupby sampling - ignore case where sample is greater than number of elements

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I can sample `a` from each grouped `b` as follows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10,20,30,40,50,60,70],
                   'b': [1,1,1,0,0,0,0]})

df.groupby('b', as_index=False)['a'].apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=3))
```

Gives:

```
b       a
0  3    40
   4    50
   5    60
1  0    10
   2    30
   1    20
```

However, if I want to sample `n` elements, then `n` must be set to at most the number of elements in a group (if we want `replace=False`)

Is there a clean way to sample `n` elements up to the maximum number of items in a group?

For example, in the given DataFrame: in `b`, there are three items with the value `1`.

If I wanted `df.groupby('b').apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=4))`, (notice `n=4`) this would break.

What's a clean way to sample up to the maximum for each group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it with `min` would be an option:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10,20,30,40,50,60,70],
                   'b': [1,1,1,0,0,0,0]})

n = 4
df.groupby('b', as_index=False)['a'].apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=min(10, len(x))))
```

Output:

```
0  3    40
   4    50
   6    70
   5    60
1  2    30
   1    20
   0    10
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Or if you always want to sample the max (i.e. random **shuffle**), use `frac`:

```
df.groupby('b', as_index=False)['a'].apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=1))
```

Output:

```
0  6    70
   4    50
   5    60
   3    40
1  2    30
   1    20
   0    10
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Note that from `pandas-1.1.0`, you can directly access [`sample` from groupby object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can adaptively modify the sample size by comparing a pre-specified max sample size with the size of the group, as so.

```
max_sample = 4
df.groupby('b')['a'].apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=max_sample if len(x)>max_sample else len(x)))
```